# Passing event result to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a visibly large `ParentComponent` with a visibly small list positioned in the middle.

I want to be able to click somewhere in the `ParentComponent`, receive event properties specific to the `ParentComponent` and pass them down to the child `ListItem` component.

I know I can accomplish this by using Ref/forwardRef, but is there a better, more obvious way that I'm not seeing?

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const clickHandler = (event) => {
        //receive event properties specific to the parent
        //and pass down to to the ListItem component from here
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={clickHandler}>
            <ul>
                <ListItem />
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a state in the parent component and store the current click event in it, then pass it down to your ListItem, so when your state is changed, your parent component will be re-rendered and you can send that event as a props down to ListItem. For example, add a state with useState to ParentComponent like this.

```
 const [clickEvent, setClickEvent] = useState();
```

Then for the onClick div function have something like this:

```
const clickHandler = event => {
   event.persist();
   setClickEvent(event);
};
```

Then pass that current event down to your ListItem like this:

```
  <ListItem event={clickEvent} />
```

Now, whenever that click event changes, your ListItem will be rerendered and get that change event.

The complete code can be found here:

[image: Edit thirsty-breeze-5zdh7]

You could always use redux too and store that event in a store that can be connected to the child component, but that could be a little overkill. It all depends on your problem.